# disable interactive logon

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to create a user for my application when deploying. I want to prevent others from loging in with this user. How do i disable the interactive logon for this user with c#?

In other words, how to set `SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight` for that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`LsaAddAccountRights`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721786%28v=vs.85%29).

Comment: And here is the c# signature for that function

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.LsaAddAccountRights

Comment: is there any managed api available or is pinvoke the only option?

Comment: since no one answers i guess no.

Answer (score -1):

If your account belongs to a windows domain:

1. Create a new OU.
2. Place this service account in this OU.
3. Now create a new Group Policy for this OU, in Security Options->Deny logon locally, add these service accounts.

Comment: -1 Deny logon locally is computer policy, not user policy.  It needs to be set on the OU containing the computer, NOT the OU containing the user account.

Comment: Also, the OP wants a programmatic solution.